# Attach and de-attach javascript functions on screen (viewport) resize, real time

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, viewport

I have this working example of my next portfolio site:
http://lantosistvan.com/temp/viewport-images/wedding.php

I have this image resize script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if( $('body').hasClass('hor') && $(window).width() >= 500 ){ // Only run the script of Body.hor and viewport width less or equal to 500px -> document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 500
var atmeretezo = function () {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height() - 24; // Jquery measuring the window height (browser viewport)
    //var windowHeight = window.innerHeight - 17;
    var headerHeight = $('header').height(); // Header height
    var footerHeight = $('footer').height(); // Footer height
    var headerFooter = headerHeight + footerHeight;
    var imagesHeight = windowHeight - headerFooter; // Real time calculate the new image height

    $('body.hor .horgallery .images li img').height(imagesHeight); // This will trigger the upper calculation

$('body.hor .horgallery .images').css({ // This will put them in the middle of the available free space (if there's any)
    'line-height': windowHeight - headerFooter + 'px',
    'height': imagesHeight + 'px'
});

};
$(document).ready(atmeretezo); // Trigger calculation
$(window).resize(atmeretezo); // Trigger line-height
}
});
```

And this Mouswheel script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if( $('body').hasClass('hor')  && $(window).width() >= 500 ){

$(".horgallery").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
  this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 75);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

}
   });

In CSS I change the layout from horizontal to vertical.

Please in windowed mode, start to bring less horizontally the browser window. My problem is that I want to attach and de-attach real-time the functions with the same functionality when you reload my page under and upper 500px screen width. But looks like some thing are stays in the DOM.

Easiest solution would be only adding and removing the "hor" class from body element, but I'm afraid DOM doesn't work that way...

Thank You for Your help!

**Update:**

I tried to add-remove the hor class from body, but some reason this script doesn't work:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
if ($(window).width() >= 500) {
    $('body').removeClass('hor');
}
if ($(window).width() < 500) {
    $('body').addClass('hor');
}
});
```

This script also breaking the image resize on native fullscreen.
**Plus, Why not removing the "hor" class from "body"?**

**UPDATE 2:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var scroller = function () {
if ($(window).width() >= 900) {
    // Attach
    $(".horgallery").on('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 75);
      event.preventDefault();
    });
}

if ($(window).width() < 900) {
    // Detach
    $(".horgallery").off('mousewheel');
}
};
$(document).ready(scroller);
$(window).resize(scroller);
});
```

Now I test this first only with mousewheel and 900px width. Seems like some reason doubles the scroll speed. Even if I just touch the browser window size.

Comment: If the easiest solution is to add/remove the `hor` class from `<body>`, and since you're already using jQuery, then can't you use some combination of [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/), [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/), and/or [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)? The DOM allows modification of classes at any time.

Comment: I updated my question with the code, when I tried to add-remove the hor class from body, but some reason that script doesn't work.

Comment: Also breaking the image resize in the native fullscreen view.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you can attach/detach listeners to elements with:

```
// Attach
$(".horgallery").on('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
  this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 75);
  event.preventDefault();
});

// Detach
$(".horgallery").off('mousewheel');
```

See [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: I updated my question. First I test on the mousewheel. It works but the problem is somehow doubles the speed of the wheel.

Comment: Try inserting console.log("test"); into the function, and open the console to check if it's being called twice.

Comment: Well, I don't know javascript, but there is a number 5, 9, 28 in front of the "test" word in the console and reaching. My other problem is why addClass and removeClass not working under if ($(window).width() >= 900) { ?